# How can I find a column vector in a matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

This may be a simple question, but how can I find a column vector in a matrix? As an example,
    `A = {{1, 2}, {0, 1}}
    b = {1, 0};`
$$\\ A=\biggl( \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \biggr)$$
$$\\ b=\biggl( \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \biggr)$$

Comment: A[[All,1]] gives the first column of the matrix A. Look at ‘Part’ for other ways to index into lists and matrices

Comment: Why not transpose the matrix and find a row instead?

Comment: Thank you both. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to use Part to actually find the index of the pertinent column instead of checking each column against b. I will try transposing the matrix though, thanks.

Comment: why is every one making this simple operation so complicated? :)  Bill comment above is all what is needed.   `A[[ All , columnNumber ]]`  This maps 1:1 to Matlab  `A(:,ColumnNumber)`  Except Mathematica uses `[[` for Matlabs `(` and `All` for Matlab `:`

Comment: @Nasser, I was assuming this was a toy example, and OP does need to find out which column of a given matrix is identical to a given list, in which case transposition is a useful first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = {{1, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 0}};
b = {1, 0};
Pick[Range[Length[First[A]]], Transpose[A], b]
```

> {1, 3}

Comment: Thank you! This does exactly what I need.

Comment: I personally would've used `Last[Dimensions[A]]` instead of `Length[First[A]]`.

Answer (score 1):

One method as suggested by J.M. (written two equivalent ways):

```
hk = Partition[A // Transpose, Length[A[[All, 1]]]] // Transpose;
{{c, d}} = Position[hk, b];
A[[All,c]]


{{c, d}} =  Position[Transpose[Partition[Transpose[A], Length[A[[All, 1]]]]], b]
A[[All,c]]
```

Comment: Why are you using `Partition`? Couldn't you simply `Position[A\[Transpose], b]`?

Comment: Thank you, this works very well also; I didn't realize that Position could be used like that.